# Setting up Apache Kafka for developer/integration test environment

Tags: apache-kafka

I am looking for advice and pointers on how to set up and run Apache Kafka on a developer & integration test environment.

I would like to avoid having to manually download and set up the whole package on each of the developers' machines and also find an easy way to start the nodes automatically when for integration tests.

Is there some sort of embedded Kafka for dev/integration test purposes (think of the H2 parallel for java developers wanting to avoid a full-fledged RDBMS)?

Do I have to resort to some sort of Vagrant solution? By the way, I have found the following interesting Gist: https://gist.github.com/svanellewee/8d978db827a860186569 but it requires setting up Vagrant+VirtualBox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some sort of embedded Kafka for dev/integration test purposes

Kafka actually includes test facilities that lets you run embedded Kafka clusters as well as unit test facilities (starting with Kafka v0.10.2.0 from 2017). See the documentation at:
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html

For example, you can add the relevant maven artifacts to your build via:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
    <!-- Replace with desired Kafka version. -->
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Documentation is available at:
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html

The following pointers will be helpful for writing tests:

- https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples -- `kafka-streams` sub-folder includes many end-to-end integration tests that spin up embedded Kafka clusters as well as, in some cases, [Confluent schema registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry).  These should be a good starting point for your own tests.
- https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/utils -- similar test facilities as in the previous link, but fewer included examples

> I would like to avoid having to manually download and set up the whole package on each of the developers' machines and also find an easy way to start the nodes automatically when for integration tests.

The above might be the easiest if your needs are covered, because it blends well into an existing development/testing process with tools like maven, gradle, or sbt.

However, if you need to perform more advanced testing -- such as intentionally taking down Kafka brokers mid-way to validate that your app survives partial outages, for example -- you might want to take a look at:

- https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/tests (system and integration tests, using e.g. docker)
- https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/vagrant
- https://github.com/confluentinc/ducktape

Answer (score 2):

I think KafkaUnit is what comes closest to H2 here. You can find it here (https://github.com/chbatey/kafka-unit).
Or just use via

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.batey.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-unit</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Works for unit/integration-tests all in one JVM, similar to Curator Testingserver.

Comment: Just to throw in an alternative (though from the looks of it I think KafkaUnit will be more comfortable to use): the SchemaRegistry code contains [classes](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/core/src/test/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/ClusterTestHarness.java) that allow you to spin up embedded Kafka instances. The "issue" is, that these reside in the test sources and confluent don't publish test jars, so you'd have to either build one yourself or just manually import the relevant files into your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for this advice relating to testing. Now do you have any idea about simplifying local developer workstation setup i.e. avoiding setting up Kafka manually on each of the developers' workstations? Think dev/local setup...

Comment: @balteo I can only speak for myself, but what I simply use in integration tests is a bash script that starts Kafka + Zk and traps a function that kills both.
Why not simply have a script checked in somewhere that does:
wget kafka (maybe to like ~/.kafka to only run the download if that folder is missing)
start zookeeper
start kafka

Comment: I had a look at the Kafka Unit plugin. It is nice but does not bring the comfort that a H2-like embedded/in memory server would provide. For instance we will have to have Kafka running somewhere in order to run integration tests on Jenkins...

Comment: I may be misunderstanding KafkaUnit, but the way I understand it is, that you don't need a Kafka running anywhere, it will spin up an embedded instance per test case and destroy it afterwards..doesn't it? At least that is what you can do with the TestHarness class from the schema registry.

Comment: Yes KafkaUnit does not require any outside process. Same as H2 imo.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood the documentation... Then it seems to fit the bill perfectly. Thanks a lot to both of you!